# wxPython statusbar

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, statusbar

How can I make the Statusbar show a specific text without having to hover one of the menubar's items? I want to make a MP3 player I'm building be able to output currently playing file in the statusbar.

Comment: Next time, if you find the (right) solution for your own question, post it as an (auto-)answer, do not edit the question to add the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
self.statusbar.SetStatusText('text', field_number)
```

Comment: If using `self.CreateStatusBar()`, do `self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()`